# Passing const value by reference

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, constants

Let's say I have this program:

```
const int width = 4;

void test(int&){}

int main() {
    test(width);
}
```

This will fail to compile. I notice that constant values ( also enumeration constants ) with names ( such as width ) cannot be passed by reference. Why is that so?

Comment: Another option is `void test(const int&){}`, which is both const and a reference.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Imagine this:

```
void test (int& j) { j++; }
```

If `test` does change the value of the thing referenced, clearly we can't call it with a const parameter. And if it doesn't, why does it take its parameter by non-const reference?

Answer (score 0):

Passing by reference allows us to change the actual object.
If an object is defined as `const`, it cannot be changed. That is exactly what const means - it's constant.